# How do i make 4 sets of 3 buttons stay clicked in at the same time?

Tags: php, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm creating 4 sets of 3 buttons that are linked together in a row. One set includes a button with a checkmark sign and a button with nothing and a button with an X. The purpose is to use the buttons to show if you're Okay with something or don't care or don't want something.

The problem is that I have 4 sets of these buttons, but I can only press down 1 button at at time for all the 4 sets! I need to press down one button per set, so there can be 4 buttons pressed at the same time.

I hope you understand my problem.

```html
<div id="midt">
  <div id="box1">
    <h1>Musik</h1>
    <input type="radio" hidden name="_groupname" value="what-gets-submitted" />
    <button type="button" class="cstm-rad1" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10003</button>

    <input type="radio" hidden name="_groupname" value="what-gets-submitted" />
    <button type="button" class="cstm-rad2" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10005</button>

    <input type="radio" hidden name="_groupname" value="what-gets-submitted" />
    <button type="button" class="cstm-rad3" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10005</button>
  </div>

  <div id="box2">
    <h1>Børn</h1>
    <input type="radio" hidden name="_groupname" value="what-gets-submitted" />
    <button type="button" class="cstm-rad1" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10003</button>

    <input type="radio" hidden name="_groupname" value="what-gets-submitted" />
    <button type="button" class="cstm-rad2" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10005</button>

    <input type="radio" hidden name="_groupname" value="what-gets-submitted" />
    <button type="button" class="cstm-rad3" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10005</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="midt2">
  <div id="box3">
    <h1>Dyr</h1>
    <input type="radio" hidden name="_groupname" value="what-gets-submitted" />
    <button type="button" class="cstm-rad1" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10003</button>

    <input type="radio" hidden name="_groupname" value="what-gets-submitted" />
    <button type="button" class="cstm-rad2" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10005</button>

    <input type="radio" hidden name="_groupname" value="what-gets-submitted" />
    <button type="button" class="cstm-rad3" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10005</button>
  </div>

  <div id="box4">
    <h1>Rygning</h1>
    <input type="radio" hidden name="_groupname" value="what-gets-submitted" />
    <button type="button" class="cstm-rad1" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10003</button>

    <input type="radio" hidden name="_groupname" value="what-gets-submitted" />
    <button type="button" class="cstm-rad2" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10005</button>

    <input type="radio" hidden name="_groupname" value="what-gets-submitted" />
    <button type="button" class="cstm-rad3" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10005</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need the css I can put that in too! :D ?

Comment: I think using a different name for each group is a solution

Comment: @jonatjano i was about to say the same thing. The name will group radio buttons in one. Use one group name (`name`) for box1, 1 for box2 etc.

Comment: I do not see PHP, but question is tagged as. You can use the snippet function to insert runnable code including html, javascript and css separated.

Comment: Yes, since there are hidden elements controled by script, I guess the visual "selected" effect  is based on CSS. It would be useful if you could add that to the snippet clicking on "edit the above snippet" after entering question edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

you can use different name for each group because that's how you group radio buttons

I also modified the `value` because that's how you can know which one is selected later in your JS

note : removed the hidden from the radio because with my browser I can't differentiate pressed button from no-pressed ones hope your css solve this ;)

```html
<div id="midt"> 
    <div id="box1">
        <h1>Musik</h1>
            <input type="radio" name="_groupname1" value="yes" />
            <button type="button" class="cstm-rad1" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10003</button>

            <input type="radio" name="_groupname1" value="noCare" />
            <button type="button" class="cstm-rad2" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10005</button>

            <input type="radio" name="_groupname1" value="no" />
            <button type="button" class="cstm-rad3" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10005</button>
    </div>

    <div id="box2">
        <h1>Børn</h1>
            <input type="radio" name="_groupname2" value="yes" />
            <button type="button" class="cstm-rad1" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10003</button>

            <input type="radio" name="_groupname2" value="noCare" />
            <button type="button" class="cstm-rad2" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10005</button>

            <input type="radio" name="_groupname2" value="no" />
            <button type="button" class="cstm-rad3" onclick="this.previousElementSibling.checked=true;">&#10005</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW thank You all! 
The solution was to change the hidden name!! :D